# What are the differences between verb and verbatim?

Tags: verbatim

What are the differences between `verb` and `verbatim`? Other than syntax, of course.

Comment: There is always a certain character which cannot be part of `\verb` text. `verbatim` always starts and ends with a new line.

Comment: `\verb` is used "in line", while `verbatim` makes a display.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [`source2e`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/source2e):

> The `verbatim` environment uses the fixed-width `\ttfamily` font, turns
>   blanks into spaces, starts a new line for each carriage return (or
>   sequence of consecutive carriage returns), and interprets every
>   character literally. I.e., all special characters `\`, `{`, `$`, etc. are
>   `\catcode`'d to "other".
>
> The command `\verb` produces in-line verbatim
>   text, where the argument is delimited by any pair of characters. E.g.,
>   `\verb #...#` takes "..." as its argument, and sets it verbatim in
>   `\ttfamily` font. The `*`-variants of these commands are the same, except
>   that spaces print as the TeXbook's space character instead of as blank
>   spaces.

In particular, the character used to delimit the contents of `\verb` cannot appear in the verbatim text. Additionally, `\verb` is meant for in-line verbatim expressions and doesn't admit carriage returns as `verbatim` does; a carriage return inside `\verb` triggers the error

```
! LaTeX Error: \verb ended by end of line.
```

The `verbatim` environment always starts and ends with a new line.

`verbatim` applies a series of additional precautions; for example, a previous use of `\parshape` won't affect the contents of the verbatim environment.