# how to make the content within \verb different line

Tags: line-breaking, verbatim

I tried to make the text contained within `\verb` different line by using `\verb#<TITLE>*\\</TITLE>#`, but the result is now what I expected:

```
<TITLE>*\\</TITLE>
```

since I want to put `</TITLE>` into the next line. So how to solve the issue?

I tried to use `verbatim` (in my thesis) as:

```
The first instruction searches an HTML document against a pattern 
\begin{verbatim}
<TITLE>*
</TITLE>
\end{verbatim}
, that it looks for the first region which starts with \verb#<TITLE># and ends with \verb#</TITLE>#.
```

It displayed as:

```
The ﬁrst instruction searches an HTML document against a pattern
<TITLE>*
</TITLE>
, that it looks for the ﬁrst region which starts with <TITLE> and ends with </TITLE>.
```

But what I like to have `<TITLE>*</TITLE>` within `verbatim` to have some inline effect, so it may look like:

```
The ﬁrst instruction searches an HTML document against a pattern <TITLE>*
</TITLE>, that it looks for the ﬁrst region which starts with <TITLE> 
and ends with </TITLE>.
```

So how to do that?

[EDIT] I finally work this around by using `\ttfamily`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To accommodate for line-breaks inside verbatim, use the `verbatim` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% For this example
\begin{document}

\verb|<TITLE> * </TITLE>|

\begin{verbatim}
<TITLE> *
</TITLE>
\end{verbatim}

{\ttfamily%
<TITLE> *

</TITLE>
}

\end{document}
```

Also see, as reference, [What are the differences between `\verb` and `verbatim`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86568/5764).

---

To insert a forced line-break within an in-line `\verb`, you can break it up into separate `\verb` commands:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% For this example
\begin{document}

The first instruction searches an HTML document against a pattern \verb|<TITLE>*|\\
\verb|</TITLE>|, that it looks for the first region which starts with \verb|<TITLE>| 
and ends with \verb|</TITLE>|.

The first instruction searches an HTML document against a pattern {\ttfamily <TITLE>*
</TITLE>}, that it looks for the first region which starts with {\ttfamily <TITLE>} 
and ends with {\ttfamily </TITLE>}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: @daiyue: See my updated answer. I also include the use of `{\ttfamily ...}` to show there's no difference. Once should (for the sake of [consistency](http://goo.gl/792Wc)) make a macro to address your font-specific requirements rather than setting things using the default `\verb` or `\ttfamily` or `\texttt`.